# President proposes bills: provenance

Tags: united-states, law, government, president, us-congress

The President of the United States sends proposed bills to members of Congress, that they may introduce the bills on his behalf. There's no provision for this in the Constitution (AFAICT).

- What was the first instance of this, and how was it received (i.e., what was the reaction)?
- When did it become a common or normal occurrence, and how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a provision in the [Constitution](http://www.archives.gov/exhibits/charters/constitution_transcript.html) for the President to propose bills to Congress.  From Article II, Section 3 (emphasis mine):

> He shall from time to time give to the Congress Information of the State of the Union, **and recommend to their Consideration such Measures as he shall judge necessary and expedient**;

While every President has had the ability to propose bills to Congress, I can't find any specific examples of either Washington or Adams doing so.  The earliest example that I found was from 1806, when [Thomas Jefferson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Jefferson#Public_policy) called upon Congress to criminalize the international slave trade.  The bill passed and Jefferson signed it into law in 1807, but it didn't take effect until January 1, 1808 (the earliest that the Constitution allowed the slave trade to be banned).

There are other notable bills proposed by Presidents throughout U.S. history.  For example, in 1909 William Howard Taft proposed a federal [income tax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Howard_Taft#Corporate_income_tax) that became the 16th Constitutional Amendment.  In 1933 Franklin Delano Roosevelt started proposing a number of bills as a part of his [New Deal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Deal).  According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_D._Roosevelt#First_New_Deal.2C_1933.E2.80.931934), "from March 9 to June 16, 1933, he sent Congress a record number of bills, all of which passed easily."  So, while every President has had the ability, FDR was the one that made its use more common.

Comment: +1, and many thanks for a well-written answer whose veracity I (can't vouch for but) have no reason to doubt. And thanks for the correction about the Constitutional basis!

Comment: "Proposing a bill to Congress" is something *anybody* can do (getting Congress to listen is the tough part).  What this part of the Constitution is saying is that the President **must** do so.

Comment: This is an excellent succinct answer.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Since it only requires that he make such recommendations as he judge necessary, and grants him total discretion in how he employs that judgment, I think "must" is too strong a term.  Nonetheless, the Constitution authorizes the President to claim that time spent ascertaining what legislation might be necessary is time spent working and for which he would be entitled to payment.

Comment: @supercat - Its the first half (with the SOTU and the "shall") that I was talking about. The other half you are right does come off as an option. My point was that this option is already available to [all Americans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_petition), so its really kind of meaningless there.

Comment: @T.E.D.: I, as a citizen, would have the right to hire my own staff with my own money to draft some proposed legislation, buy my own paper and printing supplies, and mail it to Congress using my own postage; the quoted language in the Constitution authorizes the President to fund such efforts using tax dollars.

Comment: @supercat - A good point. Not one that the relatively idle "gentleman-scholars" who wrote the document up would have thought of, but for today it probably does make a practical difference.